# SQL Oracle Select Group where all members are borrowed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: Car and CarBorrowed.

The **Car** table contains all cars in the car pool with an ID and a group the car belongs to. For example:

```
ID 1, Car 1, Group Renault
ID 2, Car 3, Group Renault
ID 3, Car 4, Group VW
ID 4, Car 6, Group BMW
ID 5, Car 7, Group BMW
```

The **CarBorrow** table contains all cars which are borrowed on a particular day

```
Car 1, Borrowed on 23.08.2012
Car 3, Borrowed on 23.08.2012
Car 5, Borrowed on 23.08.2012
```

Now I want all groups, where no cars are left (today= 23.08.2012). So I should get "Group Renault"

Comment: Have you tried anything at least? People should not answer to this type of questions.

Comment: Yes I tried the whole afternoon, but I had no idea, how to get the group, where no car is left. I only got all groups, where a car is left.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . .  One way to approach this query is to count the cars in a group and also count the cars on a particular day, then take the groups where the borrowed equals the available:

```
select borrowed.BorrowedOn, available.CarGroup
from (select c.CarGroup, count(*) as cnt
      from car c
      group by c.CarGroup
     ) available left outer join
     (select c.CarGroup, cb.BorrowedOn, count(*) as cnt
      from CarBorrowed cb join
           Car c
           on cb.CarId = c.CarId
      group by c.CarGroup, cb.BorrowedOn
     ) borrowed
     on available.CarGroup = borrowed.CarGroup
where available.cnt = borrowed.cnt
```

By the way, "Group" is a bad name for a column, since it is a SQL reserved word.  I've renamed it to CarGroup.

If the same car can be borrowed more than once on a given day, then change the `count(*)` in the second subquery to `count(distinct cb.carId)`.

If you want just one day, you can add a clause to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @FlorinGhita . . . that is a valid point. I will admit, that without a time stamp, I did make the assumption that cars cannot be borrowed twice in one day. My bigger problem is that the pool of cars might change over time, so there should be date stamps of availability in that table as well.

Comment: This looks good, but when I run it the following error occurs: 

00918. 00000 - "column ambiguously defined"

Answer (score 1):

First, join the tables, so we have for every car its borrows(a day).

```
select c.id, c.GroupName, cb.day
from car c
left join (select * from CarBorrow where day = '23 Aug 2012') cb 
  on (c.id = cb.id)
```

All cars not borrowed will have null at day.

After this, we shoud select all Groups that does not have nulls.
Bellow an trick to get it:

```
select GroupName
FROM(
    select c.id, c.GroupName, cb.day
    from car c
    left join (select * from CarBorrow where day = '23 Aug 2012') cb 
      on (c.id = cb.id)
)
group by GroupName
having count(day) = count(*)
```

(Days that are null are not counted by COUNT)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct(D1.CARGROUP)
FROM   den_car d1
MINUS
(SELECT D.CARGROUP
 FROM   den_car d
 WHERE  d.id IN (SELECT c.ID
                 FROM   den_car c
                 MINUS
                 SELECT b.id
                 FROM   den_car_borrow b
                 WHERE  B.DATE_BORROW = TO_DATE (SYSDATE)))
```

This may be optimized but the idea is simple: Find the borrowed ones, subtract it from all cars. Then find the remaning groups.

Hope it helps. (By the way of course there are lots of other ways to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution now:

```
select x.groupname from 
(select a.groupname, count(*) as cnt from car a  group by a.groupname) x 
inner join  
(
  select b.groupname, count(*) as cnt from car b   where b.carid in (select caraid from modavail where day ='23.08.2012')
  group by b.groupname
  ) y

on x.groupname = y.groupname
where  x.cnt = y.cnt and y.cnt ! = 0 ORDER BY GROUPNAME;
```

Thanks for your help!!!!